# Error in pushing changes in the remote repository

Tags: git, github

I am trying to push some changes to a remote repository from the forked repository. To do this I am using

```
$ git push --set-upstream origin my-first-branch
```

This gives me

```
remote: Permission to jquery/jquery.git denied to theo82.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/jquery/jquery.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

I know that the remote is

```
$ git remote -v
$ origin  https://github.com/jquery/jquery.git (fetch)
$ origin  https://github.com/jquery/jquery.git (push)
```

How to fix that error?

Thanks,
Theo.

Comment: try `git push --set-upstream origin/my-first-branch`

Comment: @tangoal doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
remote: Permission to jquery/jquery.git denied to theo82.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/jquery/jquery.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

The reason you are getting the above error is because **you don't have permission to push to that repository**.

Usually open source projects have a contribution guideline where they don't allow contributors to push directly to the repository. The guideline is to **create a fork, make contributions to it (commit changes and push to the fork repo) and then create a Pull Request from the fork to the original repository**.

So essentially you need to **push your changes to your fork**, and then **create a Pull Request from your branch of the fork to the master branch of the original repo on GitHub**.

You can ready more about the contribution guidelines of the **jQuery** repo [here](https://contribute.jquery.org/commits-and-pull-requests/).